# vue.config.js is not recognized- 404 error

Tags: vue.js

Vue config file is not recignized and throws a 404 error. Based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-b9KGwVECs

vue.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      //if usere requests /api path, then we add a proxy for localhost5000
      // If your frontend app and the backend API server are not running on the same host,
      // you will need to proxy API requests to the API server during development.
      "^/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: { "^/api": "/" },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

It is at the root of my frontend folder. My Vue cli version is @vue/cli 4.5.6

Originally I used this url which connected the frontend and backend perfectly
const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/posts/";

Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you restarted your Vue dev server after adding `vue.config.js` ?

Comment: If your API is on `http://localhost:5000/api`, you don't need that `pathRewrite` option...

Comment: You can also skip the `changeOrigin` as both the frontend and the API are sitting on `localhost`

Comment: Yeah I restarted my dev server. My backend (localhost:5000) seems to be responding to save changes in vue.config.js. But I am still getting 404 :(